# plot graphs in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to plot a graph of loaded csv file in R, using

```
itemFrequencyPlot(atjbill_1,topN=20,type="absolute")
```

But I am getting an error as:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘itemFrequencyPlot’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible ?

Comment: `?itemFrequencyPlot` tells you that `x` (your data matrix) needs to be of type `itemMatrix`, which it is not, hence the error. Depending on the structure of your data, you might be able to convert it.